# Node.js Bot Framework linux hosting machine traffic setup

Tags: azure, botframework, bots

I have created the very basic bot using the Node.js option as is in the steps [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/bot-framework/nodejs/bot-builder-nodejs-quickstart). It is running and the Bot Channels appID and Pass from Azure is properly in the code.

I have also (of course) filled the messaging endpoint properly.

Yet when I try to send a message from the webchat the bot doesn't receive.

So obviously, I have to set the machine networking somehow, I have already allowed the port 8080 but that didn't help. What else should I do?

I didn't find any documentation about how to set the machine hosting Microsoft Bot Framework bot, else I wouldn't be asking here. Any ideas? I know most of the people use their own hosting so someone must know how to get it connected.

Comment: Where your linux server host? And before you test in webchat, you can firstly test by requesting your nodejs web server directly in browser, to check the firewall or internet inbound settings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have had the Restify setup wrong. There are no examples as to how to setup restify for the bot in the Microsoft documentation.